# Passenger not writing fragment cache. Works when run from console as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have deployed my rails application onto a VPS which I have configured using Nginx/Passenger.

It seems to have issues when writing to a cache (if the cache exists it works fine).

When I run rails s -e production from the terminal it works fine and writes the fragment cache as it should.

I have attempted to change the file permissions on the tmp/ folder, but this failed to resolve the issue.

I imagine it is a nginx issue or server configuration, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im not fully sure. But try to move your application directory under user's home directory. Probably nginx/passenger don't have permission on writing files in your app.

Comment: Yeah thought it would be something to do with permissions. It is currently under /var/www will try in a little while to move to home folder. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the passenger process did not have permission to write to the /var/www directory, and using @itsnokolay's advice worked. (Moving to a user directory)